# mobile.de search api Authorization fehler mit PHP curl

Tags: php, api, curl, mobile

I tryed to get data from the ["mobile.de Search API"](http://services.mobile.de/manual/search-api.html), but it doesn't work =/ 
.. this error cames every time :

> HTTP Status 401 - This request requires HTTP authentication ().

.. what am I doing wrong?

```
$authCode = base64_encode("{Benutzername}:{Passwort}");
$uri = 'http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search?modificationTime.min=2012-05-04T18:13:51.0Z';
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('Authorization: '.$authCode,'Accept-Language: de','Accept: application/xml'),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => 1
));
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $out;
```

As far as I can tell, I have complied with the interface description fully.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English


Comment: Please, try to translate it in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the following curl options for a correct authorization:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ); // HTTP Basic Auth
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password); // Auth String
```

A simplified version of my implementation:

```
<?

class APIProxy {
    /* The access proxy for mobile.de search API */
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $api_base;

    function __construct(){
        /* Auth Data */
        $this->username = '{username}';
        $this->password = '{password}';
        $this->api_base = 'http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/';
    }

    function execute($query){
        /* executes the query on remote API */

        $curl = curl_init($this->api_base . $query); 
        $this->curl_set_options($curl);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $curl_error = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if($curl_error){ /* Error handling goes here */ }

        return $response;
    }

    function get_auth_string(){
        /* e.g. "myusername:mypassword" */
        return $this->username.":".$this->password;
    }

    function curl_set_options($curl){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ); // HTTP Basic Auth
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->get_auth_string()); // Auth String
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); // Throw exception on error
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // Do not retrieve header
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Retrieve HTTP Body
    }

}

$api = new APIProxy();
$result = $api->execute('ad/search?interiorColor=BLACK');
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Where to get the username and password from? Are these just the regular login data for mobile.de? Or do I need some separate auth data for the API?

Comment: Unfortunately, the standard api access costs 500€ per month. In my case, it also took over a month to get the auth data.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Turns out I only needed the search api to list some ads.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic non object oriented approach is using file get contents with manipulated header for accessing the search API. I share it to give a very simple example how the mobile.de API can be used. **However, remember file_get_contents might be 30% - 50% slower than curl.**

```
    ### Set language property in header (e.g. German) ###
    $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: de\r\n" 
        )
    );

    $baseURL = 'http://<<username>>:<<password>>@services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search?';

    $searchURL .= $searchString; ## provide get parameters e.g. color=red&make=bmw

    ##fetch your results
    $file = file_get_contents($searchURL, false, $context);
```

Regarding the auth data. **Mobile.de provides it for free for every dealer.** Just generate the auth properties in your dealer dashboard.